# Liquibase maven rollback command: [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".rollbackCount=1"

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-maven-plugin

I'm using ***Spring-Boot v3.1.3*** with ***Liquibase v4.23.1***.

The command for creating `diff` and `update` for *Liquibase* work correctly as expected:

```
- mvn liquibase:diff 
- mvn liquibase:update
```

But when I want to **rollback** the applied changelog (migration) with the command:

```
- mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1
```

I've got the error:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".rollbackCount=1". You must specify a
> valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the ...

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the forum of Liquibase site [[link]](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/unkown-lifecycle-phase-rollbacktag-versionxx/4846)

It's a little wired but in Windows OS,

I tried with **CMD** **instead** **of** **PowerShell** (or IntelliJ embedded Terminal) and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work correctly for me by adding quotation marks around the added parameter like so:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback "-Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1"
```